# R: If records match on specific columns, but differ in another, delete row where differing value is NA

Tags: r, date, na

I have a dataset and want to remove rows that have the same Patient ID, Medication, Dosage, and Start.date, but one has an end date and one doesn't. I would like to delete the row with NA End.date.

```
ID      First.name Last.name Report.year  Medication   Dosage Start.date   End.date
1       John       Doe        2013 Modulator A Dosage 1 2013-01-01       <NA>
1       John       Doe        2013 Modulator A Dosage 2 2013-01-01       <NA>
1       John       Doe        2016 Modulator B Dosage 1 2016-01-01       <NA>****REMOVE
1       John       Doe        2018 Modulator B Dosage 1 2016-01-01 2018-12-31 
1       John       Doe        2019 Modulator C     <NA> 2019-01-01       <NA>****REMOVE
1       John       Doe        2020 Modulator C Dosage 1 2019-01-01       <NA>       
1       John       Doe        2021 Modulator C     <NA> 2019-01-01 2021-12-31
```

The final result should be:

```
ID      First.name Last.name Report.year  Medication   Dosage Start.date   End.date
1       John       Doe        2013 Modulator A Dosage 1 2013-01-01       <NA>
1       John       Doe        2013 Modulator A Dosage 2 2013-01-01       <NA>
1       John       Doe        2018 Modulator B Dosage 1 2016-01-01 2018-12-31 
1       John       Doe        2020 Modulator C Dosage 1 2019-01-01       <NA>       
1       John       Doe        2021 Modulator C     <NA> 2019-01-01 2021-12-31
```

I tried the following code, but it removes all the end dates all together.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Patient.ID, Medication, Dosage, Start.date) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(End.date)==1) %>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic, but you may want: `filter(n() == 1 | !is.na(End.date))`...this would keep meds that only have one row per dosage, and if there are more than one row, it will keep the row that does _not_ have `NA` for `End.date`. Is that consistent with what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried ```data %>%
  group_by(Patient.ID, Medication, Dosage, Start.date) %>%
  filter(!(sum(is.na(End.date))!=n() & is.na(End.date))))``` and got the result I was looking for. Could you explain what the filter function does?

Comment: After you `group_by`, some of the meds/dosages have only 1 row, such as Mod A Dos 1 (the first row). Here, it seemed you wanted to keep the row, even though it had an `End.date` of `NA`. Since there's only 1 row, `n() == 1` in filter will keep this row of data. So that takes care of situations with only one row (whether or not there is an `End.date`). Then, for the other meds/dosages, you have 2 rows within your med/dosage group. The filter keeps the row that is _not_ `NA` for `End.date` in those situations. In the example, there were no situations with more than 2 rows for given med/dose...

Comment: Not sure what you would want in those situations (if they did exist).

Answer (score 1):

in Base-R. This rearranges the order of the data to ensure that the rows with End.dates != NA are kept. `c(1,5,6,7)` determines which columns you want to check for duplication.

```
df <- df[order(df$End.date),]
df[!duplicated(apply(df[,c(1,5,6,7)],1,data.frame)),]

  ID First.name Last.name Report.year Medication  Dosage Start.date   End.date
4  1       John       Doe        2018 ModulatorB Dosage1 2016-01-01 2018-12-31
7  1       John       Doe        2021 ModulatorC    <NA> 2019-01-01 2021-12-31
1  1       John       Doe        2013 ModulatorA Dosage1 2013-01-01       <NA>
2  1       John       Doe        2013 ModulatorA Dosage2 2013-01-01       <NA>
6  1       John       Doe        2020 ModulatorC Dosage1 2019-01-01       <NA>
```

example data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), First.name = c("John", 
"John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John"), Last.name = c("Doe", 
"Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe"), Report.year = c(2018L, 
2021L, 2013L, 2013L, 2016L, 2019L, 2020L), Medication = c("ModulatorB", 
"ModulatorC", "ModulatorA", "ModulatorA", "ModulatorB", "ModulatorC", 
"ModulatorC"), Dosage = c("Dosage1", NA, "Dosage1", "Dosage2", 
"Dosage1", NA, "Dosage1"), Start.date = c("2016-01-01", "2019-01-01", 
"2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"
), End.date = c("2018-12-31", "2021-12-31", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```